# Как написать банальный snow в kivy?

Tags: python, kivy

Есть где нибудь пример реализации snow на kivy framework?

По данной ссылке не очень понятно - http://apprize.info/programming/kivy_1/6.html

Comment: Объясните, пожалуйста, snow это снежинка? Или мб какой-нибудь фрактал?

Comment: Да, тоже самое, только на kivy - 
http://programarcadegames.com/python_examples/show_file.php?file=animating_snow.py

Comment: Просьба не ссылаться на другие сайты с примерами того что вам нужно -- такие вопросы (и ответы, кст) бесполезны для других участников. Да и кто даст гарантии, что тот сайт через месяц не закроется. Поэтому рекомендую перенести в ваш вопрос саму суть (под вопросом есть кнопка `править`), а ссылку можно оставить, но как дополнительная информация, а не основная. Посмотрите https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask после предложения `Как сделать хороший пример кода:`